# are braces `{` and `}` used at all in elisp?

Tags: elisp

What is the convention for using `{` and `}` characters in Emacs Lisp if they are used at all?

Do macros make use of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I tried: I opened `info` for `Elisp` and started incremental search for `{`.

Among other, `{` is used

- for Unicode character names (`"\N{SUBSCRIPT FOUR}"`)
- as quantifier operator in regular expressions (`"\\.\\{3\\}"`)
- in doc strings for modes' keymaps (`\\{colorcomp-mode-map}`)

Comment: There is an index which makes this far easier.

Comment: @wasamasa: If you mean [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Index.html), it doesn't contain `{` at all.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely the point. Braces do not carry any specific meaning.

Comment: The regular expression example should have more backslashes, e.g.: `"\\.\\{3\\}"`

Comment: In what context is the third example encountered? Certainly not in raw elisp! But in doc strings, perhaps?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: True, updated. Thanks.